# How to split text into Unicode words with Regular Expression in PHP

Tags: php, regex, unicode

I have a web site module which collects some tweets from twitter and splits them as words to put into a database. However, as the tweets usually have Turkish characters [ıöüğşçİÖÜĞŞÇ], my module cannot divide the words correctly.

For example, the phrase **Aynı labda çalıştığım** is split into **Ayn**, **labda** and **alıştığım**, but it should have been split into **Aynı**, **labda** and **çalıştığım**

Here's my code which does the job:

```
preg_match_all('/(\A|\b)[A-Z\Ç\Ö\Ş\İ\Ğ\Ü]?[a-z\ç\ö\ş\ı\ğ\ü]+(\Z|\b)/u', $text,$a);
```

What do you think is wrong here?

**Important Note: I'm not stupid not to split text by the space character, I need exactly these characters to match. I don't want any numerical or special character such as [,.!@#$^&*123456780].**

I need a regular expression that will split this
 **kısa isimleri ile "Vic" ve "Wick" vardı.**

into this:

```
kısa
isimleri
ile
Vic
ve
Wick
vardı
```

More examples:

**We're @test** would be

```
We
re
test
```

**Föö bär, we're @test to0 ÅÄÖ - 123 ok? kthxbai?** is split into this,

```
b
r
we
re
test
ok
kthxbai
```

but I want it to be:

```
Föö
bär
we
re
test
ÅÄÖ
ok
kthxbai
```

Comment: Provide more complete examples please. That include punctuation, other chars, and what you want matched from them.

Comment: And what should happen to `Föö bär, we're @test to0 ÅÄÖ - 123 ok? kthxbai`?

Comment: Why don't you just use `\pL+`? Does it really have to be a limited set of letters?

Comment: I dont know what it is @mario

Comment: @mario, I think that's what he wants, and what my answer would be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This expression would give you the desired result (according to your examples):

```
/(?<!\pL|\pN)\pL+(?!\pL|\pN)/u
```

`\pL` matches any unicode letter. The lookarounds are needed to make sure it isn't followed or preceded by numbers, to completely exclude words containing any numbers.

[Example](http://ideone.com/s30gB):

```
$str = "Aynı, labda - çalıştığım? \"quote\". Föö bär, we're @test to0 ÅÄÖ - 123 ok? kthxbai?";
preg_match_all('/(?<!\pL|\pN)\pL+(?!\pL|\pN)/u', $str, $m);
print_r($m);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Aynı
            [1] => labda
            [2] => çalıştığım
            [3] => quote
            [4] => Föö
            [5] => bär
            [6] => we
            [7] => re
            [8] => test
            [9] => ÅÄÖ
            [10] => ok
            [11] => kthxbai
        )

)
```

Comment: What if `ö` is stored as `o¨`? Don't you need to account for `\pM`s? For more see http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#grapheme

Answer (score 6):

I would take a look at [`mb_split()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-split.php).

```
$str = 'We\'re @test Aynı labda çalıştığım';
var_dump(\mb_split('\s', $str));
```

Gives me:

```
array
  0 => string 'We're' (length=5)
  1 => string '@test' (length=5)
  2 => string 'Aynı' (length=5)
  3 => string 'labda' (length=5)
  4 => string 'çalıştığım' (length=16)
```

Comment: @Qtax I took the characters directly from the OP's question.  If you're referring to grammatical incorrectness with string I couldn't help you; I don't speak Turkish. :)

Comment: Because I do not want them to be matched

Answer (score 1):

Just match for any non-space character placed between word boundries.

```
preg_match_all('/\b(\S+)\b/', $text, $a);
```

This way, it doesn't matter what characters are inside, as long as it's not a space, it'll match it.

Comment: @exculuber, how do you want that to be "split"?

Comment: Look at Charles answer, it's better than mine.